# HTML form, JSON undefined on fetch intercept of POST response

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

Serving a web page with nodejs, I've copied example code pretty much verbatim from online examples.  In chrome debugger log console I get the message:

```
(index):83 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')
```

I'm trying "fetch" operations for the first time, so I might be missing something.  I can find no mention online of why this is happening.  I did `npm install json` but that didn't help.  Nothing I've found mentions something else that should be installed or otherwise included.

Below is my code, the error is marked on the line containing "response.json()

```
<script>

   const {fetch: originalFetch } = window;
   window.fetch = async (...args) => {
      let [ resource, config ] = args;
      console.log("resource: " + resource);
      console.log("config: " + config);
      const response = await(resource, config);
      console.log(" -- got response!");
   }

   fetch("/form-1.html", { method: 'POST'})
      .then ((response) => response.json())
         .then((json) => console.log(json));

</script>
```

Comment: If you have a typo, click on the Edit button and fix it, rather than commenting about it.

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't return anything:

```
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  let [ resource, config ] = args;
  console.log("resource: " + resource);
  console.log("config: " + config);
  const response = await(resource, config);
  console.log(" -- got response!");
}
```

So any `.then()` appended to the resulting `Promise` won't receive a value.  You can `return` the value you expect:

```
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  let [ resource, config ] = args;
  console.log("resource: " + resource);
  console.log("config: " + config);
  const response = await(resource, config);
  console.log(" -- got response!");
  return response; // <--- here
}
```

---

Additionally, this is *certainly* not what you're trying to do:

```
const response = await(resource, config)
```

You're not actually calling a function, just awaiting the result of the comma operator.  So in this case `response` will just be the value of `config`.

Surely you meant this?:

```
const response = await originalFetch(resource, config)
```

Comment: since neither resource nor config are promises, `await(resource, config)` will result in the same thing as `(resource, config)` ... which is ...

Comment: @JaromandaX: Interesting.  I guess it does make sense when one remembers the comma operator.  So not an error, but definitely not what the OP wants.